# Ayuda con programa para consumir Web Service en C#

Tags: c#, webservice

Que tal soy nuevo en el tema de consumir **`web services`**, tengo un web service que realiza una petición a una base de datos para verificar si un dato (**curp**) existe o no en la misma, la respuesta de este es un valor verdadero o falso.

Mi programa funciona asi

```
[WebMethod]
        public bool ObtieneCurp( string curp)
        {
            bool existe = false;
            string sqlConStr = "cadena de conexion";
            string SQL = "SELECT *  from PAFINALMES_F_2019831 where curp='" + curp + "'";
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConStr);
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConn);
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Curp", curp);

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {

                    existe = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (rdr != null) rdr.Close();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
            return existe;
        }
```

Pero necesito hacer un programa aparte que consuma este **`web services`** es decir que el usuario introduzca el valor de su ***curp*** y el programa solo diga con un mensaje si existe en la base o no existe.

Lo estoy intentando con el siguiente código se que se usa una condición **`if else`**

pero no me funciona

```
namespace WebApplicationServices
{
    public partial class ExisteCurpValida : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_existe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ServiceReference4.ServicioEjemploSoapClient serv = new ServiceReference4.ServicioEjemploSoapClient();
            string curp = txtcurp.Text;


            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection())
            {


                if (curp != null)

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("La CURP no se encuentra en la Base de Datos") + "')</script>");
                else
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("La CURP se encuentra en la Base de Datos") + "')</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco muchisimo su ayuda

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias aclarar que es lo que no funciona? tira un error? o que cosa no hace?

Comment: Por qué creas el objeto sqlConn en el consumo del servicio? Hay muchos errores en la elaboración de tu código. Estos escenarios se han aclarado antes en otras preguntas, por favor investiga un poco mas.

Answer (score 0):

El error que veo es que no estás ejecutando le método del servicio, podrias hacerlo así:

```
 protected void btn_existe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ServiceReference4.ServicioEjemploSoapClient serv = new ServiceReference4.ServicioEjemploSoapClient();
        bool respuesta;
        respuesta = serv.ObtieneCurp("curp");

            if (respuesta != true)

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("La CURP no se encuentra en la Base de Datos") + "')</script>");
            else
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("La CURP se encuentra en la Base de Datos") + "')</script>");

    }
```

Espero te sirva hermano.

Comment: Hay mucho por corregir en el código, puedes mejorar tu respuesta :)